# dynamic HTML pagination using javascript

Tags: javascript, pagination, html-lists, code-generation, dynamic-html

I have the following pagination control
[image: The initial state]

The code for this in index.html (initial state) :

```
<ul id="page_paging">
    <li><a href="#previous_section">&lt;</a></li>
    <li id= "active_page" class="active"><span>1</span></li>
    <li><a href="#previous_section">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#previous_section">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#previous_section">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#previous_section">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#previous_section">&gt;</a></li>
</ul>
```

in javascript I'm attaching an event listener:

```
document.getElementById("page_paging").addEventListener("click", LoadPages);
```

and then in the function I'm generating the list of pages according to what the user clicks

```
function generateUL(minPage, maxPage, newActivePage){
    var innerHtml = "<li><a href=\"#previous_section\">&lt;</a></li>";

    for (var pageIdx = minPage; pageIdx <= maxPage; pageIdx++) 
    {
        if( pageIdx == newActivePage) { 
            innerHtml += "<li id= \"active_page\" class=\"active\"><span>" + pageIdx + "</span></li>";
        }
        else{
            innerHtml += "<li><a href=\"#previous_section\">" + pageIdx + "</li>";
        }
    }
    innerHtml += "<li><a href=\"#previous_section\">&gt;</a></li>" ;  

    return innerHtml;
}
```

the although the returned html looks exactly the same as the initial state "original one" -- the control looses the spaces between the  circles

the result html:

```
<ul id="page_paging">
    <li><a href="#previous_section">&lt;</a></li>
    <li id="active_page" class="active"><span>1</span></li>
    <li><a href="#previous_section">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#previous_section">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#previous_section">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#previous_section">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#previous_section">&gt;</a></li>
</ul>
```

and how the control looks
[image]

Does anyone have a clue for the reason why this is happening and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The result HTML  has different ID ("episode_paging") so CSS is likely different.
When it comes to the CODE itself instead of "#previous_section" I would use "data-page" or similar approach, belowe plain JS boilerplate:

```
<ul id="episode_paging">
    <li><a data-prev="1" href="#">&lt;</a></li>
    <li id="active_page" class="active"><span>1</span></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-page="2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-page="3">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-page="4">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-page="5">5</a></li>
    <li><a data-next="1" href="#">&gt;</a></li>
</ul>
<script>
    var inputElem = document.getElementById("episode_paging").getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputElem.length; i++) {

        inputElem[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
            if (this.getAttribute("data-page"))
                alert(this.getAttribute("data-page"));
        }, false);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The "episode_paging" is a bad 'copy paste' from my code to stackoverflow in the code both have the same id I've edited the code in my question. As for the data-page vs. href to previous_section once the user click on one of the items the page scrolls to the previous_section so it must stay as it is.

Answer (score 0):

just use a css like

```
.page_paging li {
  padding-left: 2px !important;
  padding-right: 2px !important;
}
```

For your function, I would do like this

```
function generateUL(minPage, maxPage, newActivePage){
    var innerHtml = "<li><a href=\"#previous_section\">&lt;</a></li>";
    for (var pageIdx = minPage; pageIdx <= maxPage; pageIdx++) 
    {

        if( pageIdx == newActivePage) { 
            var liElement = "<li id= \"active_page\" class=\"active\"><span>" + pageIdx + "</span></li>";
        }
        else{
            var liElement = "<li><a href=\"#previous_section\" >" + pageIdx + "</li>";
        }
        innerHtml += liElement;
    }

    innerHtml += "<li><a href=\"#previous_section\">&gt;</a></li>" ;  

    return innerHtml;
}
```

Comment: as for the code, agree. the CSS didn't change anything :(

Comment: try putting !important in your css

Answer (score 0):

Example CSS:

```
#episode_paging li {
    padding: 0 2px !important;
}

#episode_paging li a {
    padding: 0 2px !important;
}
```